# What is the best way to start NBA2K14 PS4 My Career?

Tags: nba2k14

My question is how should I make my player. For example, what is the best position, what are the first best things to upgrade, and so on... Here we go.

What height?
What position?
What to upgrade first?
What signature skill to buy?

Oh and another thing if you guys can answer is, my NBA2K14 disc case has a silver sticker on it, does it mean it's per-ordered?

Comment: Obligatory "the best is what is the most fun to you" comment.  I haven't played this game myself, but what are you trying to be best at?  Best for dunking? Best to get Rookie of the Year? ...? I would just provide some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each position is different, but there is no "best" position. However, if you want to play on a certain team, picking a position they are lacking in talent depth will help your chances of getting picked or getting play time.

Generally height is more or less tied directly to position - the tallest players being centers and the shortest being point guards. In order from shortest to tallest:

1. Point Guard
2. Shooting Guard
3. Small Forward
4. Power Forward
5. Center

Height is beneficial to every position. For example, Magic Johnson is 6'9" and was one of the greatest Point Guards of all time. In the NBA2k MyPlayer modes, being taller does make you a better player, but it slows your growth by reducing the amount of skill points you earn.

My only advice would be to focus on a few key attributes - for instance, don't put equal amount of points into midrange shooting, layups, and 3 pointers - specialize in one and focus on getting those shots. If you choose a tall power forward or center, you might want to pick something like rebounding or shot blocking as your specialty.